# Module parse error when trying to load background image in a css element

Tags: css, reactjs, algolia, next.js

It might be relevant to note that I'm using Next.js, which was already being finicky with css files (having to `npm install @zeit/next-css` just to be able to import css files into javascript pages).

So there's a specific [`Panel` element](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/panel/react/) from a third party API that doesn't have an attribute for setting background image. It should be fine, though, because they provide css mappings for all their elements, right?...

Apparently not, because when I add `background-image: url('img.png');` (the css and picture are in the same directory) to

```
.ais-Panel-header {
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
    font-size: 5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f1b68a; }
```

I get the following error

[image]

The panel works with any `background-color`. Anyway, the problem isn't element-specific, I've tried image filepaths with other elements like the body background and run into the same error. Unfortunately, since this time I'm dealing with a React component, I can't just weasel a `<body background="path">` in.

**Does anyone have any experience with this or any clue as to why this is happening and potential workarounds?**

Comment: put the image in the static folder if it works I will post an answer for why

Comment: @evgenifotia they're both in the static folder. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

next-css don't handle image loading

```
const withCSS = require("@zeit/next-css");
module.exports = withCSS({
  webpack: config => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
      use: {
        loader: "url-loader"
      }
    });
    return config;
  }
});
```